# how to change the asterisk color in required * field

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-design, material-ui

I have two required fields in my form .I want the asterisk color should be `red`.Currently it is showing black .I am using material UI react library ?
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/r7lq1jnjl4
documents
https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/

```
<FormControl>
                  <TextField
                    required
                    InputLabelProps={{
                      shrink: true
                    }}
                    id="standard-name"
                    label="Name"
                    margin="normal"
                    helperText="Some important text"
                  />
                </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Based on this [documentation on how to customize components through theme overrides](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#customizing-all-instances-of-a-component-type) for a [FormLabel (which will also include InputLabel)](https://material-ui.com/api/form-label/#__next), you should use `createMuiTheme` and add the following overrides:

```
const formLabelsTheme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiFormLabel: {
      asterisk: {
        color: '#db3131',
        '&$error': {
          color: '#db3131'
        },
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Then, you wrap your `<form>` within a `<MuiThemeProvider>` like so:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={formLabelsTheme}>
  <form noValidate autoComplete="off">

...
...
...

  </form>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Here is a [forked code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jjry2rp6lv) which demonstrates this code in action.

Since you are already creating a theme, you could just put your overrides in that theme, but you'll need to move your `<form>` to be within the `<MuiThemeProvider>` that you already have in your code.

The resulting form labels look like this:
[image: resulting form, with theme overridden]

Comment: What is the solution if I make only one field required instead of all?

Answer (score 10):

[image]

In **Mui v5** :

```
const theme = createTheme({

  components: {
    MuiFormLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
        asterisk: {color:"red"},
      },
    },
  },

})
```

Comment: This also works for checkboxes etc by customizing `MuiFormControlLabel` in the same way.

Answer (score 7):

As per the latest version of material UI. ie. `"@mui/material": "^5.0.1"`

We can do it like this:

```
 <FormLabel required>Name:</FormLabel>
```

And in the theme:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";

export const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiFormLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
        asterisk: {
          color: "#db3131",
          "&$error": {
            color: "#db3131",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who are looking answer for MUI v5 with TextField outlined variant

```
const theme = createTheme({
   components:{
     MuiInputLabel:{
          styleOverrides:{
              asterisk:{
                 color:"#d32f2f"
              }
          }
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: where did you find this info from (the documentation link), does not seem to work for FormControl along with

Answer (score 2):

Alvin's answer shows how to do this globally in your theme. You can also do this on a case-by-case basis using the [`FormLabel` asterisk class](https://material-ui.com/api/form-label/#css) via the [`InputLabel` props](https://material-ui.com/api/input-label/#props).

Below are the relevant portions from your code that I changed. Also note that the default behavior for the asterisk is for it to be red if the input is in an "error" state. For instance if you add the `error` property to the `TextField` the asterisk will be red, but that also has additional effects on styling beyond the asterisk.

```
const styles = {
  labelAsterisk: {
    color: "red"
  }
};
```

```
<InputLabel
                    FormLabelClasses={{
                      asterisk: this.props.classes.labelAsterisk
                    }}
                    required
                    shrink
                    htmlFor="age-native-simple"
                  >
                    Age
                  </InputLabel>
```

```
                  <TextField
                    required
                    InputLabelProps={{
                      shrink: true,
                      FormLabelClasses: {
                        asterisk: this.props.classes.labelAsterisk
                      }
                    }}
                    id="standard-name"
                    label="Name"
                    margin="normal"
                    helperText="Some important text"
                  />
```

```
const StyledApp = withStyles(styles)(App);
```

[image: Edit Asterisk]

Answer (score 2):

//import createTheme and ThemeProvider at the top

import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

const abc = () => {

```
//add the theme at the top of your arrow function

const theme = createTheme({

    components: {
        MuiFormLabel: {
            styleOverrides: {
                asterisk: { color: "red" },
            },
        },
    },

})
return ( // wrap your jsx with <ThemeProvider>

    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>

        <TextField required
            id="outlined-required"
            label="Full Name"
            type="text"
            size='small'
        />

    </ThemeProvider>

)
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I have changed using direct CSS class property options in the following way

```
.MuiFormLabel-asterisk {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this simple and easy

```
render(){
    const name = <p>Name<span style={{ color: "red" } >*</span></p>
    const email = <p>Email<span style={{ color: "red" } >*</span></p>
    // ...
    return (
        <div>
            <TextField type="text" label={name} />//or Input tag
            <TextField type="email" label={email} />//or Input tag
            // ...
        </div>
    )
}
```